# Apache Commons Math optimization

Tags: java, math, optimization, apache-commons-math

Does anyone have any experience with the Apache Commmons Math optimization package?  More specifically, the Nelder-Mead method implementation?  Is it pretty high quality?

Answer (score 4):

Nelder-Mead is one of the most popular multivariate optimization algorithm. The Apache implmentation is pretty good.

However, if you have more information, e.g., gradient, you should consider using a more "informed" algorithm such as BFGS. It also works with analytical gradient (using finite differencing). R uses BFGS by default, I think...

SuanShu has implemented 10+ [Java optimization](http://www.numericalmethod.com/javadoc/suanshu/com/numericalmethod/suanshu/optimization/Minimizer.html) algorithms that you can choose for your purpose.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

Note that Apache Commons Math also contains Michael Powell's direct search [BOBYQA](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/javadocs/api-3.6/org/apache/commons/math3/optim/nonlinear/scalar/noderiv/BOBYQAOptimizer.html) algorithm. This algorithm generally converges in substantially fewer iterations than the classical Nelder-Mead method, *plus* it also supports bounds on the variables.

Comment: Looks like BOBYQA is deprecated and scheduled to be removed though.  I wouldn't use it in any long-term applications

Comment: @BrianKnoblauch For reasons unknown to me, the *Apache Commons Math* optimization packages are being completely refactored and moved to other namespaces in the upcoming release. The refactored implementation of the *BOBYQA* algorithm is now available in the [org.apache.commons.math3.optim.nonlinear.scalar.noderiv](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/apidocs/org/apache/commons/math3/optim/nonlinear/scalar/noderiv/BOBYQAOptimizer.html) package. I am updating the hyperlink in the answer accordingly.